# How to extract Json data and export to csv

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2005HotfixDev14/v1/en-us/applemobilitytrends.json

Sample of JSON

```
{
"data": {
"Albania": [
{
"name": "driving",
"title": "driving",
"values": [
{
"date": "2020-01-13",
"value": "100"
},
{
"date": "2020-01-14",
"value": "95.3"
},
{
"date": "2020-01-15",
"value": "101.43"
},
{
"date": "2020-01-16",
"value": "97.2"
},
{
"date": "2020-01-17",
"value": "103.55"
```

My expected CSV output should be like (included this as a sample with only 3 rows)

```
Country   name         title        date     value
Albania  driving      driving    2020-01-13   100
Albania  driving      driving    2020-01-14   95.3
Albania  driving      driving    2020-01-15   101.43
```

in the Json there are many countries. I want to get all the data in the above format.Please help

I tried using

```
with get(URL) as req:
      json_dict = req.json()
      data = json_dict["data"]["Albania"][0]
      name = data["name"]
      title = data["title"]

       Date = []
       Value = []
       for item in data["values"]:
             date = item["date"]
             Date.append(date)
             value = item["value"]
             Value.append(value)

out = {"Country": "Albania", "name": name, "title": title, "date": Date, "value": Value}
Data = pd.DataFrame(out, index=[0])
```

i tried this but it gave an error : could not broadcast input array from shape (93) into shape (1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over all countries combine this solution with the @RoadRunner solution.

```py
from requests import get

URL = "https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2005HotfixDev14/v1/en-us/applemobilitytrends.json"


with get(URL) as req:
    json_dict = req.json()
    for key, value in json_dict['data'].items():
        country = key
        for item in value:
            for subItem in value:
                for s in subItem['values']:
                    row = {
                        "Country": key,
                        "name": item['name'],
                        "title": item['title'],
                        "date": s["date"],
                        "value": s["value"],
                    }
                    print(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be easier using [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write the rows to a CSV file:

```
from requests import get
from csv import DictWriter

URL = "https://covid19-static.cdn-apple.com/covid19-mobility-data/2005HotfixDev14/v1/en-us/applemobilitytrends.json"

with get(URL) as req:
    json_dict = req.json()
    data = json_dict["data"]["Albania"][0]
    name = data["name"]
    title = data["title"]

    # Open file for writing
    with open(
        "data.csv", mode="w", newline=''
    ) as csv_file:

        # Create dictwriter object to use for writing
        writer = DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=["Country", "name", "title", "date", "value"])

        # Write CSV headers
        writer.writeheader()

        # Write each row to CSV file
        for item in data["values"]:
            row = {
                "Country": "Albania",
                "name": name,
                "title": title,
                "date": item["date"],
                "value": item["value"],
            }
            writer.writerow(row)
```

**data.csv**

```
Country,name,title,date,value
Albania,driving,driving,2020-01-13,100
Albania,driving,driving,2020-01-14,95.3
Albania,driving,driving,2020-01-15,101.43
Albania,driving,driving,2020-01-16,97.2
Albania,driving,driving,2020-01-17,103.55
Albania,driving,driving,2020-01-18,112.67
Albania,driving,driving,2020-01-19,104.83
...
```